# Convert Json response into a Dictionary (Key value pairs) using C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, key-value

I have something like this

```
{
  "WellContactInfo": {
    "Customer": "Wintershall",
    "RigName": "Deepsea Aberdeen",
    "WellId": null
  }
}
```

I want to convert it into something like this

```
{
  "WellContactInfo": {
      {
          "name" : "Customer",
          "value" : "Wintershall"
      },
      {
        "name": "RigName",
      "value" : "Deepsea Aberdeen"
      },
      {
        "name": "WellId",
      "value" : null
      }
  }
}
```

I have a model with name WellContactInfo and values are assigned to the properties in it. Please suggest me a way on how to achieve the same. Please let me know if you need anymore information on this.

**Note:** The above Json is a sample and I have Json with multiple classes in it.

```
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; } 
        public string RigName { get; set; }
        public string WellId { get; set; } 
        //more entries

    }
```

```
 public class DownholeLoggingData
    {
        public DownholeLoggingData()
        {
            MWDCurvesDetails = new List<MWDCurvesDetails>();
            HoleSizeMap = new HoleSizeMap();

        }
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool CompressedTelemetry { get; set; } = false;
        public bool LegacyTelemetry { get; set; } = false;

        public HoleSizeMap HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
        public List<MWDCurvesDetails> MWDCurvesDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class SurfaceLoggingData
    {
        public SurfaceLoggingData()
        {
            SDLCurvesDetails = new List<SDLCurvesDetails>();
            HoleSizeMap = new HoleSizeMap();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public HoleSizeMap HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
        public List<SDLCurvesDetails> SDLCurvesDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Holesize1 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize2 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize3 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize4 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize5 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize6 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize7 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize8 { get; set; }
        //more properties
    }
```

```
public class SDLCurvesDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Holesize1 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize2 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize3 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize4 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize5 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize6 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize7 { get; set; }
        public string Holesize8 { get; set; }
        //more properties
    }
```

I know this is getting complex. But I have separate models like this. And want to convert all in to the mentioned format.

**Note :** Updated the question and added few more classes.

Current complete Json response it [here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/xNzAZni3)

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid json. Did you mean array for the `WellContactInfo` node, right?

Comment: You have a dictionary already. It would be nice if you post WellContactInfo class

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
    var wellContactInfo = new Data
    {
        WellContactInfo = ((JObject)jsonParsed["WellContactInfo"]).Properties()
                                   .Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v.Name, (string)v.Value)).ToList(),


        DownholeLoggingData = new DownholeLoggingData
        {
            Id = (int)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["Id"],
            CompressedTelemetry = (bool)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["CompressedTelemetry"],
            LegacyTelemetry = (bool)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["LegacyTelemetry"],
            HoleSizeMap = ((JObject)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["HoleSizeMap"])
                                 .ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(),
            MWDCurvesDetails = ((JArray)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["MWDCurvesDetails"])
            .Select(m => ((JObject)m).Properties().Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v.Name, (string)v.Value)).ToList()).ToList()
        }
    };
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> WellContactInfo { get; set; }
    public DownholeLoggingData DownholeLoggingData { get; set; }
}
public class DownholeLoggingData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool CompressedTelemetry { get; set; }
    public bool LegacyTelemetry { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
    public List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> MWDCurvesDetails { get; set; }
}
```

but imho it is better to create MWDCurvesDetail and define MWDCurvesDetails  as this

```
public List< MWDCurvesDetail> MWDCurvesDetails { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [@Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968106/convert-json-response-into-a-dictionary-key-value-pairs-using-c-sharp/71968348#71968348) for this help. I have made few more changes to the code and able to get the expected result.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainWorkOrderData);
            var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
            
            var finalData = new FinalData
            {
                WellContactInfo = ((JObject)jsonParsed["WellContactInfo"]).Properties()
                                           .Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>(v.Name, (string)v.Value)).ToList(),

                DownholeLoggingData = new DownholeLoggingDataDictionary
                {
                    Id = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Id", (int)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["Id"]),
                    CompressedTelemetry = new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("CompressedTelemetry", (bool)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["CompressedTelemetry"]),
                    LegacyTelemetry = new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("LegacyTelemetry", (bool)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["LegacyTelemetry"]),
                    HoleSizeMap = ((JObject)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["HoleSizeMap"])
                                         .Properties().Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v.Name, (string)v.Value)).ToList(),
                    MWDCurvesDetails = ((JArray)jsonParsed["DownholeLoggingData"]["MWDCurvesDetails"])
                    .Select(m => ((JObject)m).Properties().Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>(v.Name, v.Value)).ToList()).ToList()
                },

                SurfaceLoggingData = new SurfaceLoggingDataDictionary
                {
                    Id = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Id", (int)jsonParsed["SurfaceLoggingData"]["Id"]),
                    HoleSizeMap = ((JObject)jsonParsed["SurfaceLoggingData"]["HoleSizeMap"])
                                         .Properties().Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v.Name, (string)v.Value)).ToList(),
                    SDLCurvesDetails = ((JArray)jsonParsed["SurfaceLoggingData"]["SDLCurvesDetails"])
                    .Select(m => ((JObject)m).Properties().Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>(v.Name, v.Value)).ToList()).ToList()
                }

            };
```

```
public class DownholeLoggingData
    {
        public DownholeLoggingData()
        {
            MWDCurvesDetails = new List<MWDCurvesDetails>();
            HoleSizeMap = new HoleSizeMap();

        }
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool CompressedTelemetry { get; set; } = false;
        public bool LegacyTelemetry { get; set; } = false;

        public HoleSizeMap HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
        public List<MWDCurvesDetails> MWDCurvesDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class DownholeLoggingDataDictionary
    {
        public KeyValuePair<string, int> Id { get; set; }
        public KeyValuePair<string, bool> CompressedTelemetry { get; set; }
        public KeyValuePair<string, bool> LegacyTelemetry { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
        public List<List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>> MWDCurvesDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class SurfaceLoggingData
    {
        public SurfaceLoggingData()
        {
            SDLCurvesDetails = new List<SDLCurvesDetails>();
            HoleSizeMap = new HoleSizeMap();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public HoleSizeMap HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
        public List<SDLCurvesDetails> SDLCurvesDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

After all these changes, I am getting the below response as Json

```
public class SurfaceLoggingDataDictionary
    {
        public KeyValuePair<string, int> Id { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> HoleSizeMap { get; set; }
        public List<List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>> SDLCurvesDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

After making all these changes, I am getting the expected response as [this](https://filebin.net/y8c7eawtu0gsmqo8).